# Move unencrypted tables to encrypted sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlcipher

I want to know how to transfer my unencrypted sqlite tables to encrypted sqlite database. I'm using sqlcipher to encrypt a database.

I've tried this code, but it didn't work.

```
NSString *databasePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"contacts_enc.sqlite"];


sqlite3 *db;
if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char* key = [@"1234" UTF8String];
    sqlite3_key(db, key, strlen(key));

    if (sqlite3_exec(db, (const char*) "SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master", NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSLog(@"password is correct, or, database has been initialized") ;

        //START

        sqlite3_exec(db, "ATTACH DATABASE 'contacts.sqlite' AS encrypted KEY '1234';", NULL, NULL, NULL);
        sqlite3_exec(db, "CREATE TABLE encrypted.account(_id,username,password);", NULL, NULL, NULL);
        sqlite3_exec(db, "INSERT INTO encrypted.account SELECT * FROM account;", NULL, NULL, NULL);
        sqlite3_exec(db, "DETACH DATABASE encrypted;", NULL, NULL, NULL);

        //END
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLCipher provides a convenience function called `sqlcipher_export(…)` that will duplicate the contents of your database to another attached database.  For your scenario, please review example 1 found [here](http://sqlcipher.net/sqlcipher-api/#sqlcipher_export) within the documentation.